# Using Parse Cloud Code to enforce data integrity

Tags: parse-platform

I'm trying to create a field in Parse Cloud Code (a transaction authorization code) that once created by Cloud Code, can't be changed by the user (or anyone except Admin).  The docs indicated that this is possible.  I could really use some pointers on how to implementing such a field.  Parse reference below.

[Data Integrity in Cloud Code](https://parse.com/docs/data#security-objects)

- Not letting users directly change a calculated field

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want is described on the Parse.com blog, an entry about [dirtyKeys](http://blog.parse.com/2014/01/27/parse-objects-dirtykeys/).

Here's a copy of their sample:

```
Parse.Cloud.beforeSave(Parse.User, function(request, response) {
  for (dirtyKey in request.object.dirtyKeys()) {
    if (dirtyKey === "username" || dirtyKey === "email") {
      response.error("User is not allowed to modify " + dirtyKey);
      return;
    }
  }
  response.success();
});
```

In your case you want to do an extra check for the user to see if they are in the Admin role.

You might also want to check if the master key was used, as per [this documentation](https://parse.com/docs/js/symbols/Parse.Cloud.BeforeSaveRequest.html#master).

For reference, here's what the full query might look like:

```
Parse.Cloud.beforeSave("mySecureObject", function(request, response) {
  var isAdminQuery = (new Parse.Query(Parse.Role));
  isAdminQuery.equalTo("name", "Administrator");
  isAdminQuery.equalTo("users", request.user);
  isAdminQuery.first().then(function(adminRole) {
    if (adminRole || request.master) {
      // admin user or master key set, let 'em do what they want
    } else {
      for (dirtyKey in request.object.dirtyKeys()) {
        if (dirtyKey === "firstCalculatedField" || dirtyKey === "otherCalculatedField") {
          response.error("User is not allowed to modify " + dirtyKey);
          return;
        }
      }
    }
    response.success();
  }); // end isAdminQuery.first()
}); // end beforeSave
```